# My binary search code is too slow

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

i am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/binary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/monk-and-search-2/) algorithm task. And when i submit my code, on some test cases my code is too slow and on some my code gives wrong output. I was trying to find where i made mistake but i really couldnt. Because in test cases where my code fails there are more thousand length arrays and i cant check every output to find mistake.

So i was wondering if you could give me some advice:

1. What can i do to improve my algorithm efficiency.
2. Where i make mistake so on some test cases i get wrong output.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main
{   
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[length];

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

    int test = sc.nextInt();
    int type, check;

    for(int i=0; i<test; i++)
    {
        type = sc.nextInt();
        check = sc.nextInt();

        if(type == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(greaterOrEqualThan(arr, check, length));
        }
        else if(type == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(greaterThan(arr, check, length));
        }
    }
}

public static int greaterThan(int arr[],int x, int length)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = length-1;
    int mid;

    while( low+1 < high)
    {
        mid = (high+low)/2;

        if(arr[mid] <= x)
            low = mid;
        else if(arr[mid] > x)
            high = mid;
    }
    int startIndex;

    if(arr[low] > x && arr[low] != arr[high])
        startIndex = low;
    else if(arr[high] > x && arr[high] != arr[low])
        startIndex = high;
    else
        return 0;

    return length-startIndex;
}

public static int greaterOrEqualThan(int arr[], int x, int length)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = length-1;
    int mid;

    while(low+1 < high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;

        if(arr[mid] < x)
            low = mid;
        else if(arr[mid] == x)
        {
            high = mid;
            break;
        }
        else
            high = mid;
    }

    int startIndex;

    if(arr[low] >= x)
        startIndex = low;
    else if(arr[high] >= x)
        startIndex = high;
    else
        return 0;

    return length-(startIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: For fast I/O use `BufferedReader` or `DataInputStream` (if you can create a custom reader/writer class)

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Do you think my code is slow because of that ? Or because my binary search algorithm is bad ?

Comment: I think it's because of I/O. BTW, why do you have two binary search methods? You can do it with one method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one or both of your algorithms may be incorrect in cases where there are multiple instances of the target value in the array.  (e.g. `[1,3,3,3,5]`.

---

## Three Cases to Consider

There are three cases to consider:

1. `x` does not occur in the array
2. `x` occurs in the array exactly once
3. `x` occurs in the array more than once

---

## How To Solve

I recommend using a classical binary search algorithm for each of the two methods (the exact binary search algorithm without modification).  What you do after that is what is different.

So first, run a classical binary search algorithm, inlined directly into your methods (so that you have access to the terminal values of `low` and `high`).

Second, after the binary search terminates, test if `array[mid] != x`.  If `array[mid] != x`, then `x` does not occur in the array and it is true that `low == high + 1` (since `high` and `low` have crossed.  Therefore, the count of numbers in the array which are not less than `x` and the count of numbers in the array which are greater than `x` are both equal to `array.length - low`.

Third, if it is instead true that `array[mid] == x`, then `x` does occur one or more times in the array.  Since the classical binary search algorithm terminates immediately when if finds `x`, it is indeterminate "which" `x` it terminated on.

In this case, in order to find the count of numbers not less than `x`, you must find the "first" `x` in the array using the following code snippet:

```
do {
    mid = mid - 1;
} while (array[mid] == x);
```

`mid` will then be the index of the element immediately *before* the "first" `x` in the array, and so the count of numbers not less than `x` will be `array.length - mid + 1`.

Similarly, in order to find the count of numbers greater than `x`, you must first find the "last" `x` in the array using the following code snippet:

```
do {
    mid = mid + 1;
} while (array[mid] == x);
```

`mid` will then be the index of the element immediately *after* the "last" `x` in the array, and so the count of numbers greater than `x` will be `array.length - mid - 1`.

---

## Code

### simplified, inlined version of a classical binary search

```
int low = 0;
int high = array.length - 1;
int mid = (high + low) / 2;  // priming read

while (array[mid] != x && low <= high) {
    if (array[mid] > x)
        high = mid - 1;
    else   // (array[mid] < x)
        low = mid + 1;
    mid = (high - mid) / 2;
}
```

### not less than x

```
int countNotLessThan(int[] array, int x)
{
    /* simplified, inlined classical binary search goes here */

    if (array[mid] != x) {
        return array.length - low;
    }

    else {  // array[mid] == x
        do {
            mid = mid - 1;
        } while (array[mid] == x);
        return array.length - mid + 1;
    }
}
```

### greater than x

```
int countGreaterThan(int[] array, int x)
{
    /* simplified, inlined classical binary search goes here */

    if (array[mid] != x) {
        return array.length - low;
    }

    else {  // array[mid] == x
        do {
            mid = mid + 1;
        } while (array[mid] == x);
        return array.length - mid - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really great explanation ! I wanted to try to do binary search with my own implementation, but i guess it is way harder than i expected. But this will help me a lot to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd add a little bit to this. For many test cases, there are queries of both types (0 and 1) on the same `x`. So, instead of running binary search twice for the same value, you could use store the value of `mid` in a data structure the first time you find it and the next time you are asked to query for `x`, you can simply lookup in the data structure and use the previously calculated value. You can use a `HashMap` for this

Comment: @MiljanRakita Also, I just realized that the problem description does not specify whether the array is sorted or not.  So you would have to sort the array once in `main` before evaluating any query.

Comment: @Travis I didnt pay attention to that detail. I thought it was already sorted but it wasnt, and it was one of the reasons why my code failed so much. :)